# Saving photo on local storage and displaying it on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, frontend

Basically I have page with images - under each one of them there is like button. When being liked, the image should be saved on localStorage and then displayed on another page.

The HTML is simple (images and buttons), something like this:

```
        <img data-name="img1" src="photos/photography.jpg" >

        <button type="submit" data-name="img1">Click</button>
```

This is the jQuery. I am trying to save the liked photos in array.

```
         $('button').click((e) => {
             const data = $(e.target).data();
             let arr = $("img");
             const item = arr.filter(v => v.name === data.name)
             let cart = [];
             try {
                 cart = localStorage.getItem('cart');
                 cart = JSON.parse(cart)
             } catch (error) {}
             cart.push(item)
             localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));

         })
```

And on the page with liked images I simply get the items from local storage, but nothing seems to happen.

I would like if you can tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't do anything with cart, which had block scope btw... try without the `'let`

Comment: ^^^ take the `let` off of the `cart` in the `try`.  It's creating a lower scoped version that will not exist outside of the block.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I removed it, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your original issue is due to the mis-use of the `let` inside the try catch.  However, you can remove the try catch all together by defaulting the cart to an empty array.

```js
$('button').click(e => {
  //get the existing cart, or default to an empty new one
  let cart = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('cart') || '[]' );
  //you're only using the name, might as well grab just that
  let itemName = $(e.target).data('name');
  //find the item, same as before
  let item = $('img').filter(v => v.name === itemName);
  
  //add the item to the card
  cart.push(item);
  //put the cart back to storage
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but again nothing seems to happen. Maybe I am making a mistake in getting the items with just localStorage.getItem('cart')?

Comment: Nah, getItem just needs the key.